# How to limit the moving area of a Dojox gfx shape

Tags: dojo

Is there a way to restrict the moving area of dojox.gfx.Movable within Surface? I can move the image outside the surface in the demo of Dojo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom Mover class
http://aa3sd.net/using_dojo/draw_rectangle.html